# Error :ConnectionService not available for this version of Android

Tags: react-native, socket.io, webrtc, android-connectionservice

i am trying to use react-native callkeep to show incoming call screen.but instead i am getting the error above.does anyone know about this?

```
const options = {
  ios: {
    appName: 'My app name',
  },
  android: {
    alertTitle: 'Permissions required',
    alertDescription: 'This application needs to access your phone accounts',
    cancelButton: 'Cancel',
    okButton: 'ok',
    //imageName: 'phone_account_icon',
    //additionalPermissions: [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.example]
  }
};
RNCallKeep.setup(options).then(accepted => {console.log(accepted)});
```